# Which is the use of curly braces in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, curly-braces

The code below

```
getSpareBuffer :: Handle__ -> IO (BufferMode, CharBuffer)
getSpareBuffer Handle__{haCharBuffer=ref, 
                    haBuffers=spare_ref,
                    haBufferMode=mode}
 = do
   case mode of
     NoBuffering -> return (mode, error "no buffer!")
     _ -> do
          bufs <- readIORef spare_ref
          buf  <- readIORef ref
          case bufs of
            BufferListCons b rest -> do
                writeIORef spare_ref rest
                return ( mode, emptyBuffer b (bufSize buf) WriteBuffer)
            BufferListNil -> do
                new_buf <- newCharBuffer (bufSize buf) WriteBuffer
                return (mode, new_buf)
```

is from the GHC source code ([ghc-7.4.1\libraries\base\GHC\IO\Handle\Text.hs](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/blob/7627eab5dd882eb6f1567e3ae95c6c770830a5eb/libraries/base/GHC/IO/Handle/Text.hs#L647)). I want to know why the code uses curly braces in place of the arguments. And how the variables `haCharBuffer, haBuffers, haBufferMode` take values from `ref, spare_ref` and `mode`. These values haven't defined.

Another fragment of code from GHC that needs clarification is this:

```
flushByteWriteBuffer :: Handle__ -> IO ()
flushByteWriteBuffer h_@Handle__{..} = do
  bbuf <- readIORef haByteBuffer
  when (not (isEmptyBuffer bbuf)) $ do
    bbuf' <- Buffered.flushWriteBuffer haDevice bbuf
    writeIORef haByteBuffer bbuf'
```

In the codefile `ghc-7.4.1\libraries\base\GHC\IO\Handle\Internals.hs`
Which is the use of dots inside the braces (`{..}`)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `Handle__` data type was probably defined with record syntax, like this:

```
data Handle__ =
  Handle__
  { haCharBuffer :: IORef (...something...)
  , haBuffers :: IORef (...something...)
  , haBufferMode :: BufferMode
  }
```

The curly braces are used to match against the fields of the record type. So, the declaration says: "Check if the argument is of the `Handle__` constructor; in that case, store the value of `haCharBuffer` in `ref`, the value of `haBuffers` in `spare_ref` and the value of `haBufferMode` in `mode`"

When you write `Handle__ {..}` it's the same thing as saying `Handle__ { haCharBuffer = haCharBuffer, haBuffers = haBuffers, haBufferMode = haBufferMode }`; all the fields in the data structure are bound to their field names.

Answer (score 5):

Curly braces is used in the syntax for record types. In this code, pattern matching is used to deconstruct the record type argument into its component fields.